# php array help needed

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i need some help with a php array, I need to remove the array if the qty is 0, but I'm not sure how to do this.. my array is:

```
Array
(
    [2_Neutral] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 0
            [id] => 2_Neutral
        )

    [2_Honey] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 3
            [id] => 2_Honey
        )

)
```

As you can see 2_Neutral->qty is 0, so I would need this removed (everything to do with 2_Neutral) leaving only the 2_Honey information:

```
[2_Honey] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 3
            [id] => 2_Honey
        )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['qty'] <= 0) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

or:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function ($i) { return $i['qty'] > 0; });
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked great (I used the second example) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($yourArr as $key => $val) {
   if(empty($val['qty'])) {
      unset($yourArr[$key]);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks muchly, I think deceze got in first tho +1 for your help :)